# meaning of "to be intentionally thick"

Tags: phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context

I can't get my head around the possible meaning of this phrase - "to be intentionally thick". Is this mean to be intentionally hard to read. To be hard to see through like for example thick fog.

Phrase is from House MD episode, named 'Need to Know'

00:07:04 - You're being dramatic. - No. Actually, I'm underplaying.
00:07:07 - This is me being restrained. - It was one kiss.
00:07:10 Are you being intentionally thick?
00:07:18 This was not just a one-night stand.
00:07:22 - You can't toy with him. - I'm not.

Comment: http://www.subzin.com/quotes/M3330338df/Need+to+Know/Are+you+being+intentionally+thick%3F

Comment: Just as a note. Getting your head around something usually means that you now know the answers or have the facts but you can’t reconcile them with what you thought you knew to be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thick (colloquial) = stupid.

OED:

> **9b. Of mental faculties or actions, or of persons: Slow (or characterized by slowness) of apprehension; dense, crass, thick-headed; stupid, obtuse. Now chiefly colloquial of persons. Also emphatically, as thick as two planks, etc. Cf. thick-headed adj.**
>
> 1603   J. Hayward Answer Conf. conc. Succession iv. M j   *I omit your thicke error in putting no difference betweene a magistrate and a king.*
>
> [...]
>
> 1974   G. Honeycombe Adam's Tale i. ii. 27   ‘He must be as thick as two planks,’ said Nick.
>
> 1976   J. I. M. Stewart Memorial Service iii. 40   You might expect to become P.M. if you hadn't been so thick as to accept your idiotic life peerage.